# If I disable issues in GitHub, do I lose the current set of issues?

Tags: github, github-issues

If I disable the issue tracker in my Github repo, do I lose my current set of issues or do they re-appear when I re-enable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried this but [here](http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/34945/) seems to say your answer is No/Yes in that order:

[image: WA59780 example]

Comment: Confirmed that data is not lost.